# How to keep Firefox running [Ubuntu Linux]

Tags: 14.04

So, I was wondering if there are available commands to keep firefox running. I own a VPS, and I installed vncserver. I use my vps to upload 1 hour videos because my own internet cannot do it. Everytime I disconnect from the vncserver and get back for about 6 hours firefox is already closed and the uploads were canceled.

Ubuntu 14.04.03

Comment: Why is firefox being closed? Please run firefox from a terminal to log all eventual error messages.

Comment: When you disconnect from an SSH session, all running processes from that session are closed. Does VNC do the same thing?

Comment: Thank you for your input, guys! I found out that running firefox through terminal 'firefox &' will not close the firefox when you disconnect from the vnc server.

Answer (score 0):

To keep firefox running, you need to run it through terminal using 'firefox &'. And it should not close automatically when you disconnect from the server.